# How to update field value based on other table in mySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `report_business_likes` with relevant fields:

```
id, facebook_id, created_at,  some_info
--  -----------  -----------  ----------
1    123456789   '2013-12-23'   blabla
```

I have other table named `businesses` with followed structure:

```
id, fb_id,    data
--  -----     ----
33  123456789  xxx
```

I want to replace in `report_business_likes` field `facebook_id` with `id` from table `businesses`.

In my case, the result should be:

```
id, facebook_id, created_at,  some_info
--  -----------  -----------  ----------
1    33          '2013-12-23'   blabla
```

As you can see I replaced `123456789` with `33`.

How can I achieve that?

I tried:

```
UPDATE `report_business_likes` SET facebook_id = BZ.id from 
  (select id from `businesses` where fb_id = 123456789 ) as BZ, 
   where  facebook_id = 123456789 AND date(created_at) = '2013-12-23';
```

But get syntax error:

```
[SQL] /*SELECT * FROM `report_business_likes` where facebook_id = 123456789 AND date(created_at) = '2013-12-23';*/

UPDATE `report_business_likes` SET facebook_id = BZ from 
(select id from `businesses` where fb_id = 123456789) as BZ, 
where  facebook_id = 123456789AND date(created_at) = '2013-12-23';
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from 
(select id from `businesses` where fb_id = 123456789) as BZ,' at line 3
```

Please help,

Comment: Remove quotes in table and column names.

Comment: post the error message please

Comment: @Barranka I posted an error, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE report_business_likes 
    SET facebook_id =   (select id 
                        from businesses  
                        where facebook_id = 123456789 )
 WHERE facebook_id = 123456789 AND date(created_at) = '2013-12-23'
```

OR

```
UPDATE RBL
SET RBL.facebook_id = B.id
FROM report_business_likes RBL INNER JOIN businesses B 
ON RBL.facebook_id = B.facebook_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE report_business_likes r  JOIN businesses b  ON r.facebook_id=b.fb_id 
SET r.facebook_id=b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix the syntax. The correct syntax for `update` is:

```
update `Your table`
set `Field in yourTable` = `value or expression`
where `Conditions to filter the data in your table`
```

There's no place in the `update` syntax for a `from` clause.

Of course, if you want to update your field with the result of a subquery, you can (see M.Ali's answer).

Please take a look to the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can try by the following:

```
Update set sb.facebook_id=b.id from 
report_business _likes rb join business b on r.facebook_id=b.fb_id
```